# Is $\Vert A^n \Vert = \Vert A \Vert^n$ for normal operator $A$ on inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Exercise 7(a) after $\S$ 87. Norm from Paul R. Halmos's "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" (second edition) invites a comment on the following assertion.

> If (linear operator) $A$ is normal, then $\Vert A^n \Vert = \Vert A \Vert^n$ for every positive integer $n$.

For reference, $\S \ 87.$ Norm (from the book) has the following definition for the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ of a linear operator:

> $\Vert A \Vert = \inf \big\{K: \Vert Ax \Vert \leq K \Vert x \Vert \text{ for all vectors } x \big\}.$

Going by the discussion preceding this exercise (in the book), I assume that the assertion concerns inner product spaces, not the more general normed vector spaces. However, the inner product space, say $\mathcal V$, of the assertion is not specified to be over the complex (or real) field, and is not said to be finite-dimensional. Also, $\mathcal V$ is not given to be complete.

I am able to see why the assertion holds if $\mathcal V$ is finite-dimensional over the complex field. The reason is the spectral theorem for normal operators on such vector spaces. Similarly, I also understand that the assertion would hold in another case: if $A$ is self-adjoint and if $\mathcal V$ is finite-dimensional over the real field. I am not able to imagine what happens in the general case however, and would appreciate a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" title kind of suggests that Halmos is not talking about Hilbert spaces. And the operator norm does not change when complexifying a vector space, for normal operators it's the spectral radius even if $A$ acts on a real space.

Comment: Which norm is this? There are several norms that can be used on matrices.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I have just edited the question to include the definition of the norm used in the book.

Comment: See [Holtz-Karow, Real and Complex Operator Norms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512608).

Comment: For a complete description of normal operators on a finite-dimensional real inner product space, see Theorem 9.34 in Linear Algebra Done Right (third edition).

Comment: @ Conifold In the preface, Halmos says that he "originally intended this book to contain a theorem if and only if an infinite-dimensional generalization of it already exists". Halmos adds further that his initial intentions "are most clearly seen in the emphasis, throughout, on generalizable methods instead of sharpest possible results". In case of exercises, Halmos has specified the underlying field and the dimension of the vector space on numerous occasions. These observations make me think that Halmos wishes the reader to consider infinite-dimensional spaces (in this question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use the equivalent definition (§88) that $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$. I will first prove by a Cauchy-styled mathematical induction that $\|P^n\|=\|P\|^n$ for a positive operator $P$. In this case $\|P\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(Px,x)$ (see §89). Pick an integer $k$ such that $2^k\ge n$. Then
$$
\|P^{2^k}\|
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(P^{2^k}x,x)
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(P^{2^{k-1}}x,P^{2^{k-1}}x)
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|P^{2^{k-1}}x\|^2
=\|P^{2^{k-1}}\|^2
$$
and inductively we obtain $\|P^{2^k}\|=\|P\|^{2^k}$ and in turn $\|P\|^{2^k}=\|P^{2^k}\|\le\|P^n\|\|P\|^{2^k-n}$ by submultiplicativity. Therefore $\|P\|^n\le\|P^n\|$. Yet, by submultiplicativity, we also have $\|P^n\|\le\|P\|^n$. Hence $\|P^n\|=\|P\|^n$.

Now suppose $A$ is normal. Let $P=A^\ast A$. Then
$$
\|A^n\|
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A^nx\|
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(A^nx,A^nx)^{1/2}
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(P^nx,x)^{1/2}
=\|P^n\|^{1/2}
$$
for every positive integer $n$, where the normality of $A$ and the positivity of $P$ are used in the third and the fourth equalities respectively. Put $n=1$, we get $\|A\|=\|P\|^{1/2}$. Hence
$$
\|A^n\|=\|P^n\|^{1/2}=\|P\|^{n/2}=\|A\|^n.
$$